# Q: HTML placeholder not working in Edge

Tags: placeholder, microsoft-edge

I hope someone can help me out here. I have a form with HTML placeholders. It is done with ContactForm7 in WordPress. I have testet it in IE11, Chrome, Firefox and Safari and it works great.

But in Edge 20 it is not :-(

According to this link http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder, Edge should support it.

The form can be seen on https://www.suresms.com/dk/gratis-sms-testkonto/

Hope for some good help.

Glen

Answer (score 1):

Yep it is working in Edge.

The issue you have here is somehow linked to the 

`position: relative;`

You have in your **span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap** selector.

I removed it and it worked.

Comment: Did it help you fixing your issue?

Comment: This appears to be a known bug. https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1627778/microsoft-edge-placeholder-bug